# Adobe AIR HTML Component - socket.io

Tags: air, adobe

There is a website I'm trying to load within the HTML component that uses socket.io for some streaming information. It runs perfectly fine outside of AIR but when within the HTML component, the streaming doesn't run. It is streaming from a domain other than itself and I don't have control over either sites.

Any ideas on how to get the streaming to work within the HTML component?

Answer (score 2):

Socket.io uses websockets and unfortunately Adobe AIR's HTMLLoader doesn't support websockets : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-67c0013e126afbe6c4d-8000.html