# Can Adobe Air (AS3) use socket.io directly?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, notifications, socket.io, desktop

I have a desktop app made with Adobe Air (as3). The app will send and receive notifications over the web with online users.

I'm trying to find a way to connect Adobe Air (as3), not Flex, directly with socket.io, but I found nothing.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Apparently not: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12683505/622391

Comment: Simon, do you know another way to do this? Another idea?

I tried without socket.io, just using node.js. The receiving and sending works fine, but i don't know if its the better solution.

Comment: Sorry - my response was just based on Google. I know nothing about socket.io or Air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish? Why not just use [`NetConnection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html)? Does the server have to use `WebSockets`?

**UPDATE**: Here is an implementation of [`WebSockets` in `ActionScript`](https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket).

Comment: Hi Peter. I'm making an app with a notification system.
The app will send notifications to clients connected and the system will send notifications too. I'm using node.js with Adobe Air (as3).